Не запускается код в VSCode
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\роекты VSCode\vscode.py': [Errno 2]
No such file or directory
Когда хочу запустить код высвечивается это. Может проблема в пути? У меня папка называется Проекты VSCode, а тут роекты VSCode. В пайчарм все нормально. Версия питона 3.10.

попробуйте убрать спецсимволы (пробелы и кириллицу) из путей.

Если используете расширение codeRunner, попробуйте его отключить и запускать просто расширением python.
